# PHP Log output formatted date

Tags: php, date, posix

I want to write some logs to a file via PHP but when I want to output the date I don't find anything "standard" to simply write a complete date like : Wed Aug 13 12:38:02 2014 (and with the timezone, etc).

I found a lot of examples with the date() function but you have to pass a lot of args (and I'm not sure if it's standard). By standard I mean something POSIX compliant (or something similar), understood by any program which want to parse this log file.

Comment: I think you should take a look at Datetime: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Thx, that's what I was looking for, there are constants defined in this class that I can re-use (this is what I call standard).

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you how to format the date.
Actually, the `date` function is pretty easy to handle.

```
echo date("Y-m-d") // will output: 2014-08-13
echo date("Y-m-d H:i") // will output: 2014-08-13 16:25
```

the `date` function accepts a 2nd parameter, which is by default `time()` (so the actual timestamp).

You can specifiy the output by just adding the / changing the parameters in the brackets.
For example:

```
echo date("d.m.Y") // will output 13.08.2014
```

Comment: Have a look at my previous comment to the top of the post (and the Naruto comment) =)

Comment: agreed, maybe the better solution for a standard.